# How to pass parameters using url in Requirejs

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

On Page load I have to capture some details  from other application.

```
heretest.com/image.html?param=1&&param2=2
```

How to get values using url in Requirejs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with require.js...

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It just tend to manage a bunch of javascript file. Why do you want to use requirejs for that. Just use javascript or some other javascript framework such as angularjs.

Comment: I am using Requirejs for one application to load bunch of javascript files with html page. Here I need to get some values from aother application to run this.